# Why does this call not require 2 arguments as defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, click

Why does this code work? Specifically, why can I call the run() function with no arguments when it specifically requires both count and name. The PyLinter complains about this code and says there is no function run() with 0 arguments. But then the code runs fine.

Is this because the decorators are adding an additional function of the same name "run" but without arguments?

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def run(count, name):
    """Simple program that greets NAME for a total of COUNT times."""
    for x in range(count):
        click.echo('Hello %s!' % name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation for [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/)

Comment: Because you're calling the function returned by the click decorators, which doesn't need to have the same arity as the functions it's wrapping as long as *it* supplies the right arguments (in this case from the parsed command line arguments).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Click Commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870868/using-click-commands-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorator syntax

```
@decorator
def func():
    pass
```

is actually just syntactic sugar for:

```
def func():
    pass

func = decorator(func)
```

IOW, it rebinds the function name to the return value of the decorator - which, most often, returns another function that wraps the decorated one.

So in your example, the `run()` function you're calling in your main section is indeed not the `run()` function you defined, but the function that has been returned by your decorators - which doesn't excpects arguments instead, since the point of the decorators is to collect and provides those arguments to your original function ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this is not like a normal function, we don't need to pass parameters as we do normally.
`Click` helps you to create a command-line interface.
so when you run this at command prompt it will ask you to enter the values.

```
>>python your_file_name.py
>>Your name: Sanjay
>>Hello Sanjay!
```

Here it will print Sanjay once because default count is set to 1.

if you pass the count then it will print name multiple times

```
>>python your_file_name.py --count=3
>>Your name: Sanjay
>>Hello Sanjay!
>>Hello Sanjay!
>>Hello Sanjay!
```