# Python click hijacking stdout? Or taking over the script?

Tags: python

When I run the code below I never see the print output. Take the "click" code out and I do. So, is there a way to prevent "click" from hijacking stdout?  Running python 3.10.x on Windows from within PyCharm.

```
import click
my_cfg = { 'domains': [], 'def_domains': ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com'] } 

@click.command()
@click.option('--domain', '-d', multiple=True, type=str, nargs=1, default=my_cfg['def_domains'])
def domains(domain):
    click.echo('\n'.join(domain))
    my_cfg['domains'].append(domain)
domains()

print(f"my_cfg: {my_cfg}")
### Bunch of code here that I cannot easily move into domains() ###
```

Edit1: I'm trying to bolt click into an existing script that I'm adding command line options to. I have a bunch of code that follows domains() that I cannot easily move into domains().

Edit2: I put a breakpoint on the print() in pycharm but it doesn't seem to halt on it. And I never saw an error for using an undefined variable. So maybe click takes over?

Comment: You never even define the `cfg` variable. Is this code the same as what you're testing? Also, *calling* click-decorated functions directly never works right, it's a documented issue.

Comment: I renamed it just in case there was a conflict. I didn't even see an error, so maybe click hijacks stderr too? Or maybe that code is never called? I put a breakpoint on the print in pycharm but the debugger never halts on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does this call not require 2 arguments as defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006176/why-does-this-call-not-require-2-arguments-as-defined)

Comment: No, in that example there were two different run() functions.  I think I'm asking why can't I put more code after the bottom most run().  It seems like click needs all the work a program is going to do inside a decorator function?

Comment: @angel1200 Where are you getting that from? The questioner's code only has one function.

Comment: That said, in testing your code, I think there is indeed something weirder going on.

Comment: It appears that it's `echo` that's "hijacking" things in some fashion. If you comment out that line, the `print` works fine, even after calling the function. I'm not sure how or why it's happening, though.

Comment: The echo doesn't seem to matter. I put gibberish in ("gfshgshte") below the domains() call and Python doesn't even throw an exception. Seems like 'click' requires all the work to be done within a decorator function?

Answer (score -2):

A click command exits at the end. Put your print inside your `domains` function.

Comment: I have a bunch of code that follows that I cannot just move into domains(). I'm adding cli options to an existing script, and argparse doesn't have enough flexibility, so I'm trying to brute force click into the script.